# Boost irange with "last" argument only

Tags: c++, boost

Is there an extension of `boost::irange` that takes only one `int` argument, using 0 as the default `first` argument and the given `int` as the `last` argument in the original `irange`?

For example, I can already do this:

```
foreach(int i, irange(0, 3))
    cout << i << endl;
```

But I want the same functionality as Python's `range` function, like this:

```
foreach(int i, irange(3))
    cout << i << endl;
```

If this extension doesn't exist, I'm guessing it should be easy to write myself, but the following isn't working:

```
template<class Integer>
iterator_range< range_detail::integer_iterator<Integer> > irange(int last){
    return irange(0, last);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using your template argument. Try this instead:

```
template<class Integer>
boost::iterator_range< boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<Integer> > irange(Integer last)
{
    return boost::irange(static_cast<Integer>(0), last);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Tried this and I'm still getting: `error: no matching function for call to 'irange(int)'`

Comment: @ChrisRedford: Please show a **complete** example of the code you're using now.

Comment: Okay. Got your code to work, with modification. I'll offer an edit to you of what worked.